# Subclass extending the same superclass using another subclass within itself

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

The schema is like below

```
{
   id
   name
   surname
   employees {
      id
      name
      surname
   }
}
```

I was wondering if its oop representation could be

```
class Person {
   id
   name
   surname
}

class Employee extends Person {}

class Supervisor extends Person {
   List<Employee> employees;
}
```

So two classes will be inherited from the same class but one of them uses the other one within it self.

If this is not a good idea, what would be a better way of constructing this schema.

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea ?

Comment: Is a Supervisor a Person? Is an Employee a Person? If yes, this is fine.

Comment: Is a `Supervisor` *not* also an `Employee`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inherent issue, in a language or OO sense, with `Employee` and `Supervisor` having a common superclass, and one depending on the other as well.

There is, however, a possible issue with the suitability of that approach for modelling your particular problem domain.  In common English, most "supervisors" also have their own supervisors, and all supervisors, even the topmost, are ordinarily considered "employees" as well.  Additionally, it is unclear whether your `Person` class serves any useful purpose: if all supervisors are also employees, then does your model need to accommodate any `Person`s who are *not* employees?  It's not clear that it even makes sense to use different classes to distinguish between employees who are supervisors and those who are not.

My first inclination would be to go much simpler:

```
class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    String surname;
    List<Employee> employees;
}
```

Employees who are not supervisors would just have an empty `employees` list.  And before you ask, no, it is not a problem for `Employee` to contain a `List<Employee>`.

Comment: I'd add a `boolean isSupervisor;`. There can be supervisors with no assigned employees yet or not any longer.

Comment: Adding such a property is a possibility, @GeroldBroser, but it's a question of the desired semantics.  Specifically, one valid interpretation is that whether one is considered a supervisor or not is a function of whether one has any assigned employees.  Under that interpretation, no, by definition there cannot be supervisors without any assigned employees.  One could also be much more elaborate, say with a separate `Job` class that defines the organizational relationships, but that 's well  beyond the data schema the OP presented.